# Is this a correct implementation of Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, data-structures

Is this the correct implementation for Insertion sort. I am confused between Bubble Sort and Insertion sort and new to Data structures.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class InsertionSort{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Start entering the numbers to sort: ");
        while(reader.hasNextInt()){
            numbers.add(reader.nextInt());
        }
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
            for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
                if(numbers.get(j) < numbers.get(j-1)){
                    int temp = numbers.get(j);
                    numbers.set(j, numbers.get(j-1));
                    numbers.set(j-1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Sorted list: ");
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(" "+numbers.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow isnt a code review site. There are countless examples of the various sorting algorithms easily found with google

Comment: @redFIVE can you suggest a site where I can get it reviewed..Thanks

Comment: http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~ananth/CptS223/Lectures/sorting.pdf refer this for more details in sorting and other algorithms.

Comment: Being able to research and find answers on your own is a crucial life skill. Time to get practicing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a code-review instead of stating a specific problem. https://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Five seconds with a search engine reveals http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm and countless other implementations of insertion sort in Java. You really should do your own research. For the difference between Bubblesort and Insertion sort, you should practice doing the steps manually with a 5-element array ... on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be correct, your two nested loops don't traverse the arrays properly. Your outer loop should go from `[0, N-1)` while your inner loop should go from `(M, N)`, where `M` is the outer loop's variable. I would recommend reviewing bubble sort and insertion sort.

HackerRank has a problem with this where you can verify your program through print commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=1; i<numbers.size(); i++){
                int item = numbers[i];
                 int j = i;
                while(j>0 && numbers[j-1]>item){
                    numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
                   j--;
              }
    numbers[j] = item;
            }
```